# Repopulating form on failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for a user to create a question (in additon to user model, there's a question model, with nested answers) on their profile page. It submits from the users profile page /views/users/show.html.erb to the create action of the questions_controller.rb. If it doesn't validate, I think the default for Rails is to render the form(with the invalid information in the form for the user to edit). However, since I'm submitting the form for the question model from the users profile page the prepopulation isn't happening upon failed validation;  the user is forced to enter all the information in the form again. Is there a way in this context to get the form on the users show page to fill out with the information that was entered prior to submission?

questions_controller

```
def create
    @question = current_user.questions.build(params[:kestion])

    if @question.save
      redirect_to current_user, :notice => "Successfully created question."
    else
      ###render  :action => 'show'
      redirect_to current_user

    end
  end
```

Update
I've changed the end of the create method too

```
Redirect ( : back ), :notice => "something went wrong.try again"
```

But I still can't get the form to populate, and the validation error messages aren't showing either, only the flash notice.

Update
The show method of the users controller creates the new Question (along with the user)

```
   def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @question = Question.new 
        3.times {@question.answers.build}

   end
```

The /views/users/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
   <% if @question.errors.any? %>
  <h2><%= pluralize(@question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question
    from being saved: </h2>
    <ul>
      <% @question.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li> <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>   
  <% end %>
  <p>
     <%= f.label :content, "Question"%>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'span4', :rows => 1 %>   
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :link, "QuoraLink" %>
    <%= f.text_field :link, :class => 'span4', :rows => 1  %>   
  </p>  
  <%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
    <p>
      <%= render 'answer_fields', :f => builder %>
    </p>
   <% end %>
   <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Answer", f, :answers %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

the answer_fields partial rendered from the questions partial

```
<p class="fields">
<%= f.label :content, "Answer..." %>

  <%= f.text_field :content, :class => 'span3', :rows => 1%>

   <%= f.label :correctanswer, "Correct" %>
  <%= f.check_box :correctanswer, :class => 'span1' %>

   <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove answer", f %>      
</p>
```

Comment: how does the 'show' method looks in your UsersController? This is the method that pre-populates the form, as I understand. Also, how does the views/users/show.html.{erb,haml} view looks like? You can pass parameters there through the path parameters or through session[], but you'll likely need some changes there.

Comment: @moonfly the show method from the Users controller 'should' prepopulate the form (i.e. that's what I want) if it doesn't valiate, but it doesn't currently do that. I've updated the OP with the code that you suggested I display. Can you tell me how I could change the above code to prepopulate the form if it doesn't validate with either of the two methods you refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, in views/users/show.rb you do

```
@question = Question.new
```

that creates an empty new question. Then you populate the forms with this empty model.
What you could do instead is:

```
if session[:question]
  @question = @user.questions.new(session[:question])
  session[:question] = nil
  @question.valid? # run validations to to populate the errors[]
else
  @question = Question.new
end
```

Now all what's left to do is populating session[:question] in your questions_controller before redirecting to :controller=>"users", :action=>"show". Something like:

```
if @question.save
  redirect_to current_user, :notice => "Successfully created question."
else
  session[:question] = params[:question]
  redirect_to current_user
end
```

You may need to work on serialization/deserialization additionally for populating/using session[:question]. I didn't try to compile, so am not sure.

All this is needed because when you do redirect_to your processing of the user request ends, the user browser gets a redirect status code from your server and goes for another page, sending you a new request (which lands on the path, and eventually controller/action, to which you redirected to). So, as soon as you return from the request processing, all your variables are lost. For the next request you start from scratch.

The `render :action => "show"` approach (that was in the original scaffold and that you commented out) worked because you didn't return back to user but simply rendered the template with a specific name using the variables you already had in place (including @question, on which 'save' was called and failed, and thus internally validations were called and populated the errors object).

Actually, that reminded me that you may want to use another approach. Instead of passing parameters through session[] and redirecting to UsersController, you may want to populate all required variables and just render the view from that controller. Like below:

```
if @question.save
  redirect_to current_user, :notice => "Successfully created question."
else
  @user = current_user
  render "users/show"
end
```

Comment: I tried the second suggestion render "users/show" but ran into problem. At the top of /views/users/show.html.erb I have a navigation partial specific to the users resource. The navigation partial is missing when rendering users/show from the questions controller

Comment: The sessions solution is promising (i.e. I can repopulate the question field), but you'll notice that I not only create a new question in my show action, but also three answer fields-- 3.times {@question.answers.build}-- how do I get those to repopulate with the sessions information?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the reason that using `redirect_to` instead of `render` doesn't repopulate the form is that when you `redirect_to`, the controller logic for the action is run, whereas using `render` ignored the controller logic.

So when you `render :action => 'show'` (the "default" behaviour), it renders `show.html.erb`, with `@question` set like this:

```
@question = current_user.questions.build(params[:kestion])
```

When you `redirect_to current_user`, it renders `show.html.erb` with `@question` set using the code in your `show` action:

```
@question = Question.new 
3.times {@question.answers.build}
```

This is why you get a new (blank) form, instead of a pre-populated one.

Is it *really* that important that you use `redirect_to`? If it is, you'll need to get your `show` method to do the validation. For example, you could rewrite your `show` method to something like:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if params.has_key?(:kestion)
    @question = @user.questions.build(params[:kestion])
  else
    @question = Question.new 
    3.times {@question.answers.build}
  end
end
```

and then make your form point at that page, with something like:

```
<%= form_for(@question, url: users_path(@question.user) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

(depending on how your routes are set up and named). Of course, by that point the whole thing become horribly un-RESTful, a bit of a mess, and definitely not the Rails way of doing things. (The other, worse option would be to redirect back and pass the params through a get query.) In my opinion, you lose a lot for a minor gain, and I'm not sure that I'd really recommend it.

Comment: I agree with 'horribly un-RESTful' comment. @Michael, if I get your intentions right, you seem to want to improve the UI and allow editing the questions in place in the user form. If you do that, then probably it makes sense to make the next logical step and save/validate the questions in the UsersController#update method. Drop the QuestionsController altogether and let the UsersController take care of both models - User and Question.